# gtk liststore in glade - get column-names of liststore

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, glade

When creating an `Gtk.ListStore` in glade, you can add column names to it.
In the .glade file it looks like this:

```
  <object class="GtkListStore" id="liststore1">
    <columns>
      <!-- column-name col1 -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>
      <!-- column-name col2 -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>
    </columns>
    <data>
      <row>
        <col id="0" translatable="yes">entry</col>
      </row>
    </data>
  </object>
```

In python, loading the glade file and getting the liststore:

```
builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("file.glade")
liststore = builder.get_object("liststore1")
```

I can get the column types with `liststore.get_column_type(index)`, but I want also get the column names (`["col1", "col2"]`) that are in the glade file like xml comments.

Comment: column names on a liststore/treestore are not used in Gtk. They are used inside glade as an aid when setting up the treeview and relate the cellrenderers to the model. Glade uses libxml and probably won't use Gtk.Builder as the file parser, so it can read the comments and setup the that extra information. What's your goal though?

Comment: It's a pity, that it cannot be done. I've got some json data from the backend and wanted to map the json object keys to the models. So that the model column names would be used directly and I didn't have to write an mapping function for every view. Maybe I'll try to make it with cellrenderer ids.

Comment: Like and MVC, you populate the model then map the view to the right columns. Your model can be an Object of a certain class and then you use the TreeViewColumn/CellLayout `set_cell_data_func` method to map the right value to the renderer.

Comment: The problem is, that populating the model means mapping the json objects to it. When I have an model with columns: `(id: int, name: str)` and then get the json data: `{name: "foo", id: 1}`, I must map the `id` key to the first column and `name` key to the second. In Python, maps are unordered, so I can't just iterate through the json object.

Comment: But it's the json so generic that you don't know the contents of the json objects? The json structure it's independent of the the parsed object where you can get the pair of key/values so the fact they are "unordered" it's not important unless you are implementing a very rigid parser but i think that it's not the case. If you can elaborate maybe we can help.